# Calculating volume between polygon and raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, volume

I want to calculate the volume between a route alignment and a raster. I have the centerline of the route. The centerline is between point **A** and **B** as it is presented in the figure below. Point **A** and **B** have *X,Y,Z* so the centerline has a specific slope. Route width is 8 meters as I buffered (Yellow polygon).

Do you know a method to calculate the valume between the polygon and the DEM below?

Or do you know any other way of calculating the volume?

I can use both *arcpy* or *ArcToolbox*.

[image]

Comment: Calculate end points of polyline and convert them to 3d points. Create 3d line from them. Convert polygon to line and interpolate it using your Dem. Create tin, etc.

Comment: I think if he interpolates the line with the DEM, the volume should be equal to zero... and it's not what he wants.

Answer (score -1):

1. Enable the 3D analyst extension
2. In ArcToolbox go to 3D Analyst Tools > Functional surface > Surface volume
   and just fill the tool accordingly

For more explanation, just watch this 5minutes [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDUmpzaE84o)

Comment: how do I define a polygon with slope?

Comment: You said points A and B have their coordinate in X,Y,Z and the road is buffered at 8m. 

You can compute the polygon slope by yourself.


Lets assume that A coordinates are (Xa,Ya,Za) and B coordinates are (Xb,Yb,Zb):

Then the slope is (Zb-Za)/(Xb-Xa)

Comment: The polyline has slope. But, when I buffer it to get a 8 meter width polygon, the polygon has no slope and I cannot see it 3D in arcscence.

Comment: Calculation of line slope is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I think if he applies your methodology the volume will be zero because the layer is an interpolation from the DEM.
I think my answer is correct